# Pandas convert datetime64 [ns] columns to datetime64 [ns, UTC] for mutliple column at once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `query_df` and some of the columns are in `datetime[ns]` datatype.

I want to convert all `datetime[ns]` to `datetime[ns, UTC]` all at once.

This is what I've done so far by retrieving columns that are `datetime[ns]`:

```
dt_columns = [col for col in query_df.columns if query_df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
```

To convert it, I can use `pd.to_datetime(query_df["column_name"], utc=True)`.

Using `dt_columns`, I want to convert all columns in `dt_columns`.
How can I do it all at once?

Attempt:

```
query_df[dt_columns] = pd.to_datetime(query_df[dt_columns], utc=True)
```

Error:

> ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month,
> day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing

Answer (score 3):

You have to use lambda function to achieve this. Try doing this

```
df[dt_columns] = df[dt_columns].apply(pd.to_datetime, utc=True)
```

Comment: Any solution without using lamda function? It's slow

Comment: How about converting the whole df. Something like this. df[dt_columns].astype('datetime64[ns, UTC]')

Comment: I have INTEGER, FLOAT and OBJECTS in the dataframe

Comment: But, since you are selecting the columns with only datetime64[ns] already using dt_columns. You are filtering out the other columns when using df[dt_columns]

Answer (score 1):

First part of the process is already done by you i.e. grouping the names of the columns whose datatype is to be converted , by using :

```
dt_columns = [col for col in query_df.columns if query_df[col].dtype == 'datetime64[ns]']
```

Now , all you have to do ,is to convert all the columns to datetime all at once using pandas apply() functionality :

```
query_df[dt_columns] = query_df[dt_columns].apply(pd.to_datetime)
```

This will convert the required columns to the data type you specify.

EDIT:

Without using the lambda function

step 1: Create a dictionary with column names (columns to be changed) and their datatype :

```
convert_dict = {}
```

Step 2: Iterate over column names which you extracted and store in the dictionary as key with their respective value as datetime :

```
for col in dt_columns:
    convert_dict[col] = datetime
```

Step 3: Now convert the datatypes by passing the dictionary into the astype() function like this :

```
query_df = query_df.astype(convert_dict)
```

By doing this, all the values of keys will be applied to the columns matching the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt `query_df[dt_columns] = pd.to_datetime(query_df[dt_columns], utc=True)` is interpreting `dt_columns` as year, month, day. Below the example in the help of `to_datetime()`:

```
Assembling a datetime from multiple columns of a DataFrame. The keys can be
common abbreviations like ['year', 'month', 'day', 'minute', 'second',
'ms', 'us', 'ns']) or plurals of the same

>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2015, 2016],
...                    'month': [2, 3],
...                    'day': [4, 5]})
>>> pd.to_datetime(df)
0   2015-02-04
1   2016-03-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Below a code snippet that gives you a solution with a little example. Bear in mind that depending in your data format or your application the UTC might not give your the right date.

```
import pandas as pd 
 
query_df = pd.DataFrame({"ts1":[1622098447.2419431, 1622098447], "ts2":[1622098427.370945,1622098427], "a":[1,2], "b":[0.0,0.1]}) 
query_df.info() 
 
# convert to datetime in nano seconds 
query_df[["ts1","ts2"]] = query_df[["ts1","ts2"]].astype("datetime64[ns]") 
query_df.info() 
 
#convert to datetime with UTC 
query_df[["ts1","ts2"]] = query_df[["ts1","ts2"]].astype("datetime64[ns, UTC]") 
query_df.info()
```

which outputs:

> ```
>    <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>     RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
>     Data columns (total 4 columns):
>      #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype  
>     ---  ------  --------------  -----  
>      0   ts1     2 non-null      float64
>      1   ts2     2 non-null      float64
>      2   a       2 non-null      int64  
>      3   b       2 non-null      float64
>     dtypes: float64(3), int64(1)
>     memory usage: 192.0 bytes
>     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>     RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
>     Data columns (total 4 columns):
>      #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype         
>     ---  ------  --------------  -----         
>      0   ts1     2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
>      1   ts2     2 non-null      datetime64[ns]
>      2   a       2 non-null      int64         
>      3   b       2 non-null      float64       
>     dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(1), int64(1)
>     memory usage: 192.0 bytes
>     <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>     RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
>     Data columns (total 4 columns):
>      #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype              
>     ---  ------  --------------  -----              
>      0   ts1     2 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
>      1   ts2     2 non-null      datetime64[ns, UTC]
>      2   a       2 non-null      int64              
>      3   b       2 non-null      float64            
>     dtypes: datetime64[ns, UTC](2), float64(1), int64(1)
>     memory usage: 192.0 byte
> ```